# Build a multidimentional array from multiple tables

Tags: php, sql, arrays, joomla, foreach

I'm trying to build a multidimensional array base on a single array... please let me explain.
I have a very basic query as follow.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
    ->select('o.*, u.*, i.*')
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__redshop_orders', 'o'))
    ->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__redshop_users_info', 'u').' ON (' . $db->quoteName('u.users_info_id') .' = '. $db->quoteName('o.user_info_id').')')
    ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__redshop_order_item', 'i') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('i.order_id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('o.order_id') . ')')
     ->where($db->quoteName('o.order_number') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote($o_id) .'');
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

that will output a single $key per order, say the user has 3 orders it will display

```
array (
[0] => array ( 'id 1', 'data42')
[1] => array ( 'id 1', 'data26')
[2] => array ( 'id 1', 'data27')
)
```

the idea is to make a single multidimensional array as follow

```
array (
[id1] => array (
                      [user 1] => array ( 
                                                 [order 1] => ( array => [item 1] => 2, [item 2] => 3 )
                                              )
                     )
)
```

in other words...

```
[user 1]
        [order id 1]
                    [items 1]
                    [items 2]
                    [items 3]
        [order id 2]
                    [items 15]
                    [items 25]
                    [items 33]
[user 2]
        [order id 46]
                    [items 1]
                    [items 2]
                    [items 3]
        [order id 25]
                    [items 15]
                    [items 25]
                    [items 33]
```

that type of array is what I'm looking for, for I'm having a hard time to build that array...
Now, that query display all the information that I want just not the way I need

I also made 3 other queries 1 for the user, 1 for the orders and 1 for the items, but I don't see how to put it together...

the ID's that can be use to relate one another are

order_id which is in the users table user_id which is in the orders table and item_id which is in the orders table...

I was using this foreach to put them together but is not working....

```
$user = array();
$order = array();
$items = array();
foreach ($results as $user) {
    $id = $user->order_id;
    $user->orders = array();
    $order[$id] = $user;

    if ($user->order_id == 0) {
        $user[$id] = & $orders[$id];
    }

    foreach ($order as $id => & $node) {
        if (isset($order[$node->order_id])) {
            $order[$node->order_id]->children[$id] = $node;
        }
    }
}

print_r($user);
```

but is not working...

and here is the array that I need to work with as an example...

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [order_id] => 3
            [user_id] => 374
            [order_number] => 3
            [barcode] => 
            [user_info_id] => 1
            [order_total] => 594.00
            [order_subtotal] => 394.00000
            [order_tax] => 0.00
            [order_tax_details] => 
            [order_shipping] => 200.00
            [order_shipping_tax] => 0.00
            [coupon_discount] => 0.00
            [order_discount] => 0.00
            [special_discount_amount] => 0.00
            [payment_dicount] => 0.00
            [order_status] => P
            [order_payment_status] => Partial Paid
            [cdate] => 1393522811
            [mdate] => 1393522811
            [ship_method_id] => g7aKj0A==
            [customer_note] => 
            [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
            [encr_key] => 0k61
            [split_payment] => 0
            [invoice_no] => 
            [mail1_status] => 0
            [mail2_status] => 0
            [mail3_status] => 0
            [special_discount] => 0.00
            [payment_discount] => 0.00
            [is_booked] => 0
            [order_label_create] => 0
            [vm_order_number] => 
            [requisition_number] => 
            [bookinvoice_number] => 0
            [bookinvoice_date] => 0
            [referral_code] => 
            [customer_message] => 
            [shop_id] => 
            [order_discount_vat] => 0.000
            [track_no] => 
            [payment_oprand] => -
            [discount_type] => 
            [analytics_status] => 0
            [tax_after_discount] => 0.000
            [recuuring_subcription_id] => 
            [users_info_id] => 1
            [user_email] => fake@emaisl.com
            [address_type] => BT
            [firstname] => Chychy
            [lastname] => Hush
            [vat_number] => 
            [tax_exempt] => 0
            [shopper_group_id] => 1
            [country_code] => USD
            [address] => The address #2
            [city] => Basds
            [state_code] => 
            [zipcode] => 01000
            [phone] => 1234569875
            [tax_exempt_approved] => 0
            [approved] => 0
            [is_company] => 0
            [ean_number] => 
            [braintree_vault_number] => 
            [veis_vat_number] => 
            [veis_status] => 
            [company_name] => 
            [requesting_tax_exempt] => 0
            [accept_terms_conditions] => 0
            [order_item_id] => 3
            [supplier_id] => 0
            [product_id] => 15
            [order_item_sku] => 139-1310-1
            [order_item_name] => Soe other names items 3
            [product_quantity] => 2
            [product_item_price] => 10.0000
            [product_item_price_excl_vat] => 10.0000
            [product_final_price] => 20.0000
            [order_item_currency] => $ 
            [product_attribute] => 
            [product_accessory] => 
            [delivery_time] => 0
            [container_id] => 0
            [stockroom_id] => 1
            [stockroom_quantity] => 2
            [is_split] => 0
            [attribute_image] => 
            [wrapper_id] => 0
            [wrapper_price] => 0.00
            [is_giftcard] => 0
            [giftcard_user_name] => 
            [giftcard_user_email] => 
            [product_item_old_price] => 0.0000
            [product_purchase_price] => 0.0000
            [discount_calc_data] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [order_id] => 3
            [user_id] => 374
            [order_number] => 3
            [barcode] => 
            [user_info_id] => 1
            [order_total] => 594.00
            [order_subtotal] => 394.00000
            [order_tax] => 0.00
            [order_tax_details] => 
            [order_shipping] => 200.00
            [order_shipping_tax] => 0.00
            [coupon_discount] => 0.00
            [order_discount] => 0.00
            [special_discount_amount] => 0.00
            [payment_dicount] => 0.00
            [order_status] => P
            [order_payment_status] => Partial Paid
            [cdate] => 1393522811
            [mdate] => 1393522811
            [ship_method_id] => Adflvra tr6g7aKj0A==
            [customer_note] => 
            [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
            [encr_key] => 0e90k61
            [split_payment] => 0
            [invoice_no] => 
            [mail1_status] => 0
            [mail2_status] => 0
            [mail3_status] => 0
            [special_discount] => 0.00
            [payment_discount] => 0.00
            [is_booked] => 0
            [order_label_create] => 0
            [vm_order_number] => 
            [requisition_number] => 
            [bookinvoice_number] => 0
            [bookinvoice_date] => 0
            [referral_code] => 
            [customer_message] => 
            [shop_id] => 
            [order_discount_vat] => 0.000
            [track_no] => 
            [payment_oprand] => -
            [discount_type] => 
            [analytics_status] => 0
            [tax_after_discount] => 0.000
            [recuuring_subcription_id] => 
            [users_info_id] => 1
            [user_email] => fake@emaisl.com
            [address_type] => BT
             [firstname] => Chychy
            [lastname] => Hush
            [vat_number] => 
            [tax_exempt] => 0
            [shopper_group_id] => 1
            [country_code] => USD
            [address] => The address #2
            [city] => Basds
            [state_code] => 
            [zipcode] => 01000
            [phone] => 1234569875
            [tax_exempt_approved] => 0
            [approved] => 0
            [is_company] => 0
            [ean_number] => 
            [braintree_vault_number] => 
            [veis_vat_number] => 
            [veis_status] => 
            [company_name] => 
            [requesting_tax_exempt] => 0
            [accept_terms_conditions] => 0
            [order_item_id] => 4
            [supplier_id] => 0
            [product_id] => 6
            [order_item_sku] => 139-2011-DS-1
            [order_item_name] => Name 3 for prod
            [product_quantity] => 3
            [product_item_price] => 80.0000
            [product_item_price_excl_vat] => 80.0000
            [product_final_price] => 240.0000
            [order_item_currency] => $ 
            [product_attribute] => 
            [product_accessory] => 
            [delivery_time] => 0
            [container_id] => 0
            [stockroom_id] => 1
            [stockroom_quantity] => 3
            [is_split] => 0
            [attribute_image] => 
            [wrapper_id] => 0
            [wrapper_price] => 0.00
            [is_giftcard] => 0
            [giftcard_user_name] => 
            [giftcard_user_email] => 
            [product_item_old_price] => 0.0000
            [product_purchase_price] => 0.0000
            [discount_calc_data] => 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [order_id] => 3
            [user_id] => 374
            [order_number] => 3
            [barcode] => 
            [user_info_id] => 1
            [order_total] => 594.00
            [order_subtotal] => 394.00000
            [order_tax] => 0.00
            [order_tax_details] => 
            [order_shipping] => 200.00
            [order_shipping_tax] => 0.00
            [coupon_discount] => 0.00
            [order_discount] => 0.00
            [special_discount_amount] => 0.00
            [payment_dicount] => 0.00
            [order_status] => P
            [order_payment_status] => Partial Paid
            [cdate] => 1393522811
            [mdate] => 1393522811
            [ship_method_id] => v5amlvra tr6g7aKj0A==
            [customer_note] => 
            [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
            [encr_key] => 0e01661
            [split_payment] => 0
            [invoice_no] => 
            [mail1_status] => 0
            [mail2_status] => 0
            [mail3_status] => 0
            [special_discount] => 0.00
            [payment_discount] => 0.00
            [is_booked] => 0
            [order_label_create] => 0
            [vm_order_number] => 
            [requisition_number] => 
            [bookinvoice_number] => 0
            [bookinvoice_date] => 0
            [referral_code] => 
            [customer_message] => 
            [shop_id] => 
            [order_discount_vat] => 0.000
            [track_no] => 
            [payment_oprand] => -
            [discount_type] => 
            [analytics_status] => 0
            [tax_after_discount] => 0.000
            [recuuring_subcription_id] => 
            [users_info_id] => 1
            [user_email] => fake@emaisl.com 
            [address_type] => BT
            [firstname] => Chychy
            [lastname] => Hush
            [vat_number] => 
            [tax_exempt] => 0
            [shopper_group_id] => 1
            [country_code] => USD
            [address] => The address #2
            [city] => Basds
            [state_code] => 
            [zipcode] => 01000
            [phone] => 1234569875
            [tax_exempt_approved] => 0
            [approved] => 0
            [is_company] => 0
            [ean_number] => 
            [braintree_vault_number] => 
            [veis_vat_number] => 
            [veis_status] => 
            [company_name] => 
            [requesting_tax_exempt] => 0
            [accept_terms_conditions] => 0
            [order_item_id] => 5
            [supplier_id] => 0
            [product_id] => 49
            [order_item_sku] => 150-1017-0
            [order_item_name] => Poducs names 1
            [product_quantity] => 2
            [product_item_price] => 67.0000
            [product_item_price_excl_vat] => 67.0000
            [product_final_price] => 134.0000
            [order_item_currency] => $ 
            [product_attribute] => 
            [product_accessory] => 
            [delivery_time] => 0
            [container_id] => 0
            [stockroom_id] => 
            [stockroom_quantity] => 
            [is_split] => 0
            [attribute_image] => 
            [wrapper_id] => 0
            [wrapper_price] => 0.00
            [is_giftcard] => 0
            [giftcard_user_name] => 
            [giftcard_user_email] => 
            [product_item_old_price] => 0.0000
            [product_purchase_price] => 0.0000
            [discount_calc_data] => 
        )

)
```

so thats what my query outputs.... there is 1 user 1 order 3 items in the order...

Thank you for taking the time...

Comment: What does 

[u_datas] => // everything from user table
        [u_datas] => // everything from user table

represen i.e. why have that twice? Also is [order]  indented by accident or do you mean it to be on teh same leve as [u_datas]?

Comment: well, I was trying to simplify things as I explained, [u_data] => 1 ... could be [user_name] => John, the next key could be [user_email] => the actual array is huge, it has, name, email, address, phone, and some other information related to the user... the other keys [i_datas], [o_datas] could be.. [items_price], [item_name]... about 30 keys per item and o_data... [order_id], [order_price, dates, card_type...] about 60 keys... as you can see is huge!...

Comment: I think you need to work on your query to make it deliver the code with the structure you want.  You want one user row per user so the joins you are doing are not helping.  WHat you might need to start with is writing multiple separate queries that give you the pieces with the structure you want and build the object you want, and then work on combining them together into one query, maybe (sometimes a quick trip to the database for a simple query is faster than one query with complex joins). I think you may want to be using UNIONs in some cases rather than joins.

Comment: That query is working fine, it outputs the information I need, say a user has 3 orders it will display the 3 main keys plus if each order has 3 items each it will display 9 keys total, now, say the user only has 1 order and 1 item in the order, that query will display a single array, the first array in here is showing 3 order for a single user... now, I have change my query to 3 queries total, 1 for the user, 1 for the orders and 1 for the items, each query is working, question is how do I put it together!...  thank you...

Comment: So each one is an object, the user object(s), the order object(s) the items object(s) and items should be nested in orders and orders nested in users. So you want the user to have an order property that is an array of order objects.   And you want the order objects to have item property that is an array of item objects.  Do you want them for a list of users or just one? You have to think is it better  to use php or is it better to try to use sql. For php obviously you can do it by looping though the results and composing your object.

Comment: The request is not per user but for all of the orders in the DB, the query that I have now is giving me the information I have requested, in my actual DB there are about 300 demo orders, or fake orders... about 2000 fake users... and for this exerciser I have output an array of 1 user 1 order and 3 item, if you want to see the array is there in the description at the end, that array is the output from the query at the binging of my question, all I need to do is build a multidimensional array, but the foreach that I have is not working...